# Homomorphic Multiplication Operation in BFV Scheme

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I am working on BFV scheme and trying to create a very simple Python implementation. I am following the [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144.pdf) by Fan and Vercauteren. Most of the operations are easy to implement but I am having difficulty implementing homomorphic multiplication operation.

In the page 10 of the paper, the computation of $c_0$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are defined as:

```
[round(t*(Some Polynomial Arithmetic)/q)]_q
```

where `[*]_q` is applying modulo `q` to each coefficient of the resulting polynomial.

Here, I think that I should use a carrier modulus ($Q$) besides regular modulus ($q$) where size of $Q$ is at least $\log(n) + 2 \cdot \log(q)$.

In other words, I should follow the steps:

1. all inputs should be converted to based $Q$ from base $q$ first (no cost since I am investigating the case with single $q$ and single $Q$).
2. Then polynomial multiplication (utilizing NTT) and addition should be performed in base $Q$.
3. After that, $(t/q)$ should be multiplied with the coefficients of the result and rounding operation should be applied.
4. Finally, the resulting polynomial should be reduced to base $q$.

After multiplication operation, I apply relinearization and decryption operations. However, I cannot obtain the original plaintext. Is there something wrong in the steps I defined above?

Comment: I'll leave the $\TeX$ encoding bit within the code statements for somebody who has read the paper.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes!

Comment: @acmert were you able to make any progress here? I'm running into a similar problem (see: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80962/implementing-bfv-relinearization)